# Gitlab shared runner safety doubts

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gitlab-ci-runner

My plan is to use GitLab pipeline to build maven application and deploy it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. During research I found [this](https://medium.com/dowebthings/how-to-deploy-from-gitlab-to-elastic-beanstalk-aws-cdac7b701004) page.

> If you are using gitlab.com there is a shared runner by default which you can use. Note this runner is shared with other users that means it may mean you have to wait in a que until another user’s build has completed, cannot scale and also mean that you may not use the shared runner builds including **variables which may be exposed** in a shared runner.

I'm confused. All builds are done inside the docker, so as far as I understand, there is no way to see my code, credentials to deploy or built artifacts. So is it safe to use shared runner in my case? I just want to make sure that my code, credentials / keys to deploy and build jar is safe.

Exaple code:

```
development:
  type: deploy
  environment: production
  script:
  - mkdir ~/.aws/
  - touch ~/.aws/credentials
  - printf "[eb-cli]\naws_access_key_id = %s\naws_secret_access_key = %s\n" "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" >> ~/.aws/credentials
  - touch ~/.aws/config
  - printf "[profile eb-cli]\nregion=ap-southeast-1\noutput=json" >> ~/.aws/config
  - eb deploy funwitheb-production
  only:
  - master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sent email to author of article. 
Article is from 2016. This information is not up to date. So probably this is not problem anymore.
Here is more information:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/docs/security/index.md

> Docker can be considered safe when run in non-privileged mode. To make such
>   setup more secure it's advised to run jobs as user (non-root) in Docker containers
>   with disabled sudo or dropped SETUID and SETGID capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any solid Gitlab-docs based proof after searching for a while but I've also never made it to actually read other user's variables while executing a job on a shared runner.

I also can't find any GitLab issues related to this (ie. someone "accidentally" seeing someone else's vars) so security/privacy-wise it looks fine.